# Why i am getting "Field is not writable: OpportunityShare.UserOrGroupId" compile time error

Tags: apex, opportunity, sharing, apex-managed-sharing

I am getting compile time error while trying to assign `userId` to `opShare.UserOrGroupId` field. I am not sure what is wrong in it -

```
    List<OpportunityShare> grantAccessUpsertLst = new List<OpportunityShare>(); 
    for(String userId : userIds){
            List<UserRecordAccess> userRecords = [SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId =: userId AND RecordId =: oppId];
            if(userRecords.size() > 0 && !(userRecords.get(0).HasEditAccess)){
                OpportunityShare opShare = new OpportunityShare();
                opShare.UserOrGroupId = userId; // Error Line
                opShare.OpportunityAccessLevel = ACCESS_LEVEL_EDIT;
                opShare.OpportunityID = oppId;
                grantAccessUpsertLst.add(opShare);          
            }
    }
    if(grantAccessUpsertLst.size() > 0)
        upsert grantAccessUpsertLst;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<OpportunityShare> grantAccessUpsertLst = new List<OpportunityShare>(); 
for(String userId : userIds){
        List<UserRecordAccess> userRecords = [SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId =: userId AND RecordId =: oppId];
        if(userRecords.size() > 0 && !(userRecords.get(0).HasEditAccess)){
            OpportunityShare opShare = new OpportunityShare();
            opShare.UserOrGroupId = userId; // Error Line
            opShare.OpportunityAccessLevel = ACCESS_LEVEL_EDIT;
            opShare.OpportunityID = oppId;
            grantAccessUpsertLst.add(opShare);          
        }
}
if(grantAccessUpsertLst.size() > 0)
    insert grantAccessUpsertLst;//Use Insert instead of upsert
```

You can use insert to share opportunity share. Also if you want to update any share records you will need to first delete the existing share records for the user and insert the new one. Hope this helps.

Comment: does OpportunityShare not support "Upsert"?

Comment: No .Its not updatable and hence no upsert allowed.It will support insert though

Comment: It supports upsert as well. I didn't get any exception while using upsert keyword.

Answer (score 1):

As of the salesforce doc for the [Opportunity Share object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunityshare.htm):

> *UserOrGroupId*: ID of the User or Group that has been given access to
>   the opportunity. 
> **This field can’t be updated.**

[image]

Comment: If this is the case then how can i share an opportunity with user using Apex code?

Comment: @PramodKumar I have answered please check